# Utilizar métodos de uma DLL

Tags: delphi, api, dll

Estou precisando utilizar métodos de uma DLL que foi desenvolvida por terceiros. Tenho somente o arquivo ".DLL".

A documentação da DLL é escassa... existe um exemplo de execução do método que preciso em VB

```vb
Private Const TamMsgErro As Long = 1000
Dim oTED As New clsGeraMidiaTed
Dim lResult As Long
Dim sMsgErroTED As String * TamMsgErro

'Chamada no Projeto
Set oTED = CreateObject("PRGerarMidiaTED.clsGeraMidiaTED")

lResult = oTED.Gerar_MidiaTEDDat(sListaArqEntrada, _
                                 sArqSaida, _
                                 sTipoDoc, _
                                 sMsgErroTED, _
                                 TamMsgErro)
If lResult <> 0 Then
  MsgBox sMsgErroTED
Else
  MsgBox "Arquivo [" & sArqSaida & "] gerado com sucesso !"
End If
```

Preciso desenvolver em Delphi, e o problema que estou tendo é que o método "Gerar_MidiaTEDDat" não é exportado pela DLL. Este método está em uma classe na DLL.

Utilizando o PE Explorer consegui obter os seguintes dados da DLL:

```vb
//PRGerarMidiaTED
//Version: 1.0
PRGerarMidiaTED;
GUID = {DA0AA6B5-73AC-41B7-BBA5-DF03D6367C63};

Dispatch _clsGeraMidiaTed;
  GUID = {EEF15A9A-5C3E-45A0-B876-4E10381C7D2E};
  function QueryInterface(riid: ^GUID; out ppvObj: ^^VOID); stdcall;
  function AddRef: UI4; stdcall;
  function Release: UI4; stdcall;
  function GetTypeInfoCount(out pctinfo: ^UINT); stdcall;
  function GetTypeInfo(itinfo: UINT; lcid: UI4; out pptinfo: ^^VOID); stdcall;
  function GetIDsOfNames(riid: ^GUID; rgszNames: ^^I1; cNames: UINT; lcid: UI4; out     rgdispid: ^I4); stdcall;
  function Invoke(dispidMember: I4; riid: ^GUID; lcid: UI4; wFlags: UI2; pdispparams: ^DISPPARAMS; out pvarResult: ^Variant; out pexcepinfo: ^EXCEPINFO; out puArgErr: ^UINT); stdcall;
  function Gerar_MidiaTEDDat(sListaArqEntrada: BSTR; sArqSaida: BSTR; sTipoDoc: BSTR; out sMsgErro: ^BSTR; lTamMsgErro: I4): I4; stdcall;
  function Verificar_VersaoGerarMidiaTED(out sVersaoGerarMidia: ^BSTR; out sMsgErro: ^BSTR; lTamMsgErro: I4): Bool; stdcall;

CoClass clsGeraMidiaTed;
GUID = {664BF784-A2D6-477B-8022-1F32FDD90FD6};
```

Nas funções exportadas o PE Explorer me indicou que existe a função `DllGetClassObject` que deve ser utilizada para obter a instancia da classe, porém não encontrei exemplos de como fazer isto.

Alguma sugestão ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa dll deve ser uma biblioteca de tipos(`Type Library`).
Para utilizar ela primeiramente você deve registrar ela com o utilitário `regsvr32.exe`do windows.

```
    regsvr32 "caminho para a dll"
```

Após isso você tem duas alternativas para utilizar ela no Delphi.

#### Utilizando o Assistente fornecido pela IDE

Que se localiza em `Component->Import Component...`.

- Nele você deve selecionar `Import a Type Library`
- Procurar a dll desejada na lista
- Na proxima tela você pode selecionar o local onde o arquivo com as definições vai ser criado e também se vão ser criados componentes para encapsular as classes da dll.
- No ultimo passo você pode selecionar se

  - somente vai ser criado uma unit com as definições
  - se ela vai ser instalada em um pacote existente
  - em um novo pacote
  - ou se vai ser adicionada ao projeto

Somente a 2º e a 3º adiciona o componente a paleta.

Depois disso você só deve adicionar a unit uses do arquivo desejado e criar a classe como cria qualquer outro componente.

O nome das classes vão ser algo como `TNomedaClasse`

#### Utilizando a função `CreateObject`

De forma semelhante ao exemplo que você postou.

```
const
  TamMsgErro : Integer= 1000
var
 oTED : Variant;
 lResult : Integer;
 sMsgErroTED : String;
 lResult : Integer;
begin

'Chamada no Projeto
oTED := CreateObject("PRGerarMidiaTED.clsGeraMidiaTED");

lResult = oTED.Gerar_MidiaTEDDat(.....);
```

Comment: Eu recomendo utilizar sempre a primeira opção, pois ela gera um stub. É muito mais fácil trabalhar com o stub do que com o OleVariant que o CreateObject cria.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma classe sua para mapear a dll ou carregá-la dinamicamente

**Primeiro declare o tipo de função q vc deseja chamar**

```
type
    TTipoFuncao = function (sListaArqEntrada: BSTR; sArqSaida: BSTR; 
        sTipoDoc: BSTR; out sMsgErro: ^BSTR; lTamMsgErro: I4): I4;
```

**Depois no seu local de ativação vc carrega a dll, mapeia o método e o executa**

```
var
    Dll :THandle ; 
    funcao: TTipoFuncao;
    Retorno: I4;
begin 
    Dll := LoadLibrary(NomeDll);
    if DLL = 0 then
        //MostraMsgErro
    else
    begin 
        @funcao := GetProcAddress(Dll,´Gerar_MidiaTEDDat´);
        if @funcao nil then
            Retorno := funcao( ParâmetroDesejado );
        FreeLibrary(Dll);
    end;

    //Use o retorno :D
end;
```

**Caso de criar a classe**

Primeiro deve-se mapear o tipo da função, como no exemplo anterior

```
type
    TTipoFuncao = function (sListaArqEntrada: BSTR; sArqSaida: BSTR; 
      sTipoDoc: BSTR; out sMsgErro: ^BSTR; lTamMsgErro: I4): I4;
```

Em seguida criar a classe que mapeia

```
type
  TMidiaTeD = class(TObject)
  private
    FTedMidia: TTipoFuncao;
    FDLL: THandle;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function Gerar_MidiaTEDDat(sListaArqEntrada: BSTR; sArqSaida: BSTR; sTipoDoc: BSTR; out sMsgErro: ^BSTR; lTamMsgErro: I4): I4;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMidiaTeD.Create;
begin
  Dll := LoadLibrary(NomeDll);
  if DLL = 0 then
      //MostraMsgErro

  @FTedMidia := GetProcAddress(Dll,´Gerar_MidiaTEDDat´);
end;

destructor TMidiaTeD.Destroy;
begin
  FreeLibrary(Dll);
  inherited;
end;

function TMidiaTeD.Gerar_MidiaTEDDat(sListaArqEntrada: BSTR; sArqSaida: BSTR; sTipoDoc: BSTR; out sMsgErro: ^BSTR; lTamMsgErro: I4): I4;
begin
  Result := FTedMidia(sListaArqEntrada, sArqSaida, sTipoDoc, sMsgErro, lTamMsgErro);
end;
```

**PS:** Os tipos aparentemente são string e integer, mas mantive os mesmos do seu exemplo para vc validar.

Comment: Felipe,
O problema é que não é possível obter diretamente o método `Gerar_MidiaTEDDat` utilizando `GetProcAddress`, pois este método não é exportado pela DLL.

O método que existe exportado (pelo que identifiquei) é o `DllGetClassObject`... a partir dele eu obteria a classe e a partir dela teria que buscar o método `Gerar_MidiaTEDDat`.

Comment: Desulpe @Vinicius, tinha entendido errado. Talvez esses links te ajudem nisso: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954973/putting-classes-in-a-dll] ou [http://talkdelphi.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/how-to-import-object-from-dll.html]

Comment: @FelipeCaputo, o segndo link está quebrado exibindo a mensagem "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist. "

Comment: @Stribus ele tinha ficado com um ] no final, Obrigado pelo aviso. Segue agora correto: http://talkdelphi.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/how-to-import-object-from-dll.html